# QT movie processing on GPU

Tags: cocoa, macos, gpu, qtkit

I'm working on a QTKit project in cocoa where the QT movie is taking up ~70% of the CPU load. I would like to move some of the processing load onto the GPU, if possible. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Comment: You need to determine whether the reduction in computational cost would outweigh the costs of transferring data to and from GPU memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Snow Leopard, use `initWithAttributes:error:` to create the QTMovie object, and include the `QTMovieOpenForPlaybackAttribute` attribute with a value of `YES`. This will use QuickTime X to decode/play the movie, which, if possible, [will play it with GPU acceleration](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/snowleopard/quicktimex.html).

Be aware that this locks out *a lot* of functionality. You really do need to only be using the movie for playback. [The QuickTime Kit Application Programming Guide has more information.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/QuickTimeX/QuickTimeX.html)

Comment: Peter you've answered two of my questions on Cocoa dev so far, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Install a GPU QuickTime codec for the movie format you want to support ? Apparently such things exist, e.g. CoreAVC.